# Why is the quotient map $G\rightarrow G/T$ a fibration?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups

I have just learnt about fibrations and I saw somewhere the following. Given a compact lie group $G$, one can consider a maximal torus $T$ of $G$ then the quotient map $G\rightarrow G/T$ is a fibration. Does anyone know why this is true?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you aware that the map is a fiber *bundle*? That is to say it is locally a projection $T\times R^k\rightarrow R^k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a corollary of a result of Ehresman: If $p:M\rightarrow N$ is a submersion between compact connected manifolds, it is a locally trivial fibration.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann%27s_lemma

Comment: I guess as Tim commented this shows that it is a fiber bundle, but how can we then argue it is a fibration. I guess it would suffice to show that G/T is compact. But is that true?

Comment: Yes, it is true since the image of a compact set by a continuous map is compact.

Comment: @TheGeometer saying it's a fiber bundle is a stronger statement. Fiber bundles are fibrations where every fiber is homeomorphic to the same space.

Comment: Not any fiber bundle is a Hurewicz fibration, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119115/example-of-fiber-bundle-that-is-not-a-fibration , but it is always a Serre fibration, which is sufficient for most purposes.